# How to join 2 telephone wires to pull through wall

Tags: phone-wiring

I need to replace my old telephone (4 pairs) with a new one probably 10 pair cable. The path already contains some other wires too and looks like no new cable can be inserted. My question is how I can connect 2 wires i.e. the old and new one so that while pushing form one side joint stays there.

As there are multiple corners inside the wall path which some are 90 degree and some even more, so I need to join in a way which is solid as well thin.

Comment: Many times I use the original wires to pull a new one in. The more 90’s the harder it gets, if stapled or nailed it can be impossible to pull a new cable.  The ability to push pull new cables depends on if it is stapled or not in lots of homes.

Comment: the old wire is not stappled

Comment: Do you have an attic?

Answer (score 1):

OK, start out by stripping the main cover insulation about an inch off of each end of the cables. Now strip a half inch of insulation off of each conductor. Twist the conductors from one cable to the next separately trying to keep even tension. You'll have to group some of the 10 pair conductors together and then twist them to a 4 pair conductor. Lay the twisted splices flat and pull slightly to even out the tension. If you have a soldering iron you can solder the joints together for added strength. Then wrap one layer of electrical tape as tight as you can from the edge of the cover insulation across the spliced area to the edge of the cover insulation on the other cable.  Then wrap one layer of electrical tape from one inch over the cover insulation across the splice area to one inch over the cover insulation of the other cable.

You now have a strong straight slice about the same thickness as the cable. If you are trying to push pull this through concealed studs you'll still have a problem with the 90 degree bends, especially if the studs are steel. If you have access to an attic, run a new route across the attic and down the walls as needed. Good luck.

Comment: Having done this more times than I care to remember, I would suggest to strip back 2 to 3” of insulation then stagger the soldered joints - this allows the joint to bend easier...

Comment: @Solar Mike Good point. I threw the solder bit in as an after thought.